# Given $P(A \cup B)$ and $P(B)$, find $P(A \cap B^c)$

Tags: probability

I am having a hard time figuring this out.

$P(B) = 0.5$, so of course $P(B^c) = 0.5$.

We are also given $P(A \cup B) = 0.6$.

Since $P(B) = P(B^c)$,

$\implies P(A \cup B) = P(A \cup B^c) = 0.6$.

We know $P(A \cup B^c) = P(A) + P(B^c) - P(A \cap B^c)$

Rearrange to get

$P(A \cap B^c) = P(A) + P(B^c) - P(A \cup B^c)$

Substituting, we have

$P(A \cap B^c) = P(A) + 0.5 - 0.6$

$P(A \cap B^c) = P(A) - 0.1$.

Am I on the right track here? How do I deduce $P(A)$?

Comment: Why don't you draw a Venn diagram first ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Write the *inclusion-exclusion formula* and note  $\{A\cap B^c,A\cap B\}$ is a partition of $A\;$ (if $A\cap B\neq \varnothing$, but this case is trivial) and deduce a general formula.

Comment: Oh! After looking at the Venn diagram this is very clear now. Thank you for the hint.

Comment: It's only the formal translation of the Venn diagram…